# Debug android app in google play

Tags: android, debugging

I need to use APK Expansion Files on Google Play. Is it possible to test the functionality of this mechanism in my program without publication of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test some functionality without uploading it to Google Play, while the downloading part requires you to upload a draft application to Google Play, as specified and explained in great detail in [this part](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing) of the documentation (which Google lead me to in a few seconds).